# Maintain C++ Object, using its method depending on UI

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an issue that need to be resolve:

I have a java with native method that create an object and utilize method of that object. 
 this is my java code:
I have a java file called IssmJni and it contain a native method:

```
public static native long fac(long n);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("FacLib");
    }
public static long facIterative(long n)
{
    return fac(n);
```

in my main class I have this:

```
long result = IssmJni.facIterative(Long.parseLong(input));
    System.out.println(result);
```

this is my C++ code:
main file:

```
static jlong factorial(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jlong n)
    {
        fac *f = new fac();
        jlong result = (jlong) (f->factorial(n));
        delete(f);
        return (jlong) result;
    }
```

header file:

```
class fac
{
    public:
    long factorial(long n);
};
```

fac.cpp:

```
#include "com_lan_factorial_FacLib.h"
#include "fac.h"

long fac::factorial(long n)
{
    long f = 1;
    long i;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
         f *= i;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Everything works fine, so what happen is that the UI will feed a number, called the C++ code and generate a new object call fac, and use the method factorial in that class fac.
by this line

fac *f = new fac();
            jlong result = (jlong) (f->factorial(n));

What I want is to keep the same object fac, but utilize factorial method with the different input. I try to stay away from pthread because it is too complicated. Is there a way that I can create another java thread and keep this object alive throughout the entire process of my app, and use that factorial whenever I have new user input. then get rid of this object when the app die?

In sum, I want to keep 1 instance of object fac, and use factorial method many times. Is it possible without doing native pthread?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is what I come up with.

```
static fac* pfac = NULL;

namespace com_lan_factorial
{
    static jlong factorial(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jlong n)
    {
        pfac = new fac();
        jlong result = (jlong) (pfac->factorial(n));
        return (jlong) result;
    }

    static jlong factorial_ten(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
    {
        jlong result = (jlong) (pfac->factorial(3));
        return (jlong) result;
    }
```

so i create a pointer called pfac, upon the first run pfac will be assign to a new object pfac = new fac(); upon the second run I just reused the pfac pointer and recall the factorial function. This completely works, But I am not sure if this create 2 fac objects here with 2 factorial method, or just 1 fac method and the same factorial method. can anyone verify please. thanks